# UltraGrid SQL update only visible rows

Tags: c#, sql, ultrawingrid

I have a ultragrid table with filled data:

[image]

I want to set the visible rows to `kd_aktiv = 0`

I have a

```
`foreach` (`UltraGridRow` row in `ultraGridVorgaenge.Rows`)
```

at the moment and then a command like this "`UPDATE KUNDEN SET KD_AKTIV = 0`" but it updates all of the customer to 0 but I want only the visible.

Do I have to do it with a where at the end of the SQL statement?

Comment: of course you should use `where` at the end of your SQL statement.

Comment: But how can I get the kd_numm from the visible rows in the where?